# Agregar objetos a una lista en un bucle Java

Tags: java, poo, bucle-for, arraylist, bucles

tengo el siguiente problema al agregar objetos en una lista mediante un bucle, el problema es que solo se guarda el ultimo resultado en toda la lista.

***Codigo:***

```
        List<datoComunVo> resultdc = new ArrayList<datoComunVo>();
        datoComunVo rdc = new datoComunVo();
        String result = "";
        List<Valor> listaV = new ArrayList<Valor>();
        List<datoComun> listaDc = new ArrayList<datoComun>();
        listaDc = dcrepositorio.findallDatoComun();
        listaV = valorepositorio.findAllByIdCodf(codf);

        for (int cont1 = 0; cont1 < listaDc.size(); cont1++) {
            for (int dc = 0; dc < listaV.size(); dc++) {
                if (listaV.get(dc).getPreguntas_valor().equals(listaDc.get(cont1).getEtiqueta())) {
                    
                        String valquery = listaDc.get(cont1).getQuery();
                        String nuevo = valquery.replace(":PAR_PIDM", "" + pidm);
                       //resultado de un query que guardo en una propiedad del objeto
                        result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(nuevo, String.class);

                        //Guardo los valores en el objeto
                        rdc.setRespuesta(result);
                        rdc.setEtiqueta(nuevo);
                        System.out.println("objeto" + rdc.getRespuesta());

                        guardo los objetos en la lista
                        resultdc.add(rdc);
                }
            }
        }
        return resultdc;
```

***el problema es que al ejecutarse el for si me traen los valores reales***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***pero al guardar los objetos en la lista solo me guarda el ultimo valor en toda la lista***
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es porque estás añadiendo siempre el mismo objeto de tipo `rdc`. Es decir, sólo lo creas al inicio fuera del for. En Java los objetos se guardan por referencia y cuando haces el `add` estás añadiendo la misma referencia, por eso sólo ves el último valor.

Para corregirlo prueba a crear una instancia nueva cada vez como aquí:

```
List<datoComunVo> resultdc = new ArrayList<datoComunVo>();
        
        String result = "";
        List<Valor> listaV = new ArrayList<Valor>();
        List<datoComun> listaDc = new ArrayList<datoComun>();
        listaDc = dcrepositorio.findallDatoComun();
        listaV = valorepositorio.findAllByIdCodf(codf);

        for (int cont1 = 0; cont1 < listaDc.size(); cont1++) {
            for (int dc = 0; dc < listaV.size(); dc++) {
                if (listaV.get(dc).getPreguntas_valor().equals(listaDc.get(cont1).getEtiqueta())) {
                    
                        String valquery = listaDc.get(cont1).getQuery();
                        String nuevo = valquery.replace(":PAR_PIDM", "" + pidm);
                       //resultado de un query que guardo en una propiedad del objeto
                        result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(nuevo, String.class);

                        //Guardo los valores en el objeto
                        datoComunVo rdc = new datoComunVo();
                        rdc.setRespuesta(result);
                        rdc.setEtiqueta(nuevo);
                        System.out.println("objeto" + rdc.getRespuesta());

                        guardo los objetos en la lista
                        resultdc.add(rdc);
                }
            }
        }
        return resultdc;
```

Como ves, `datoComunVo rdc = new datoComunVo();` está dentro del for en cada iteración

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya corregí el error